# php and send mail

Tags: php, email, smtp

I search to send mail with php script.

```
$mail = new PHPmailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host='mail.mydomaine.com';
$mail->From='xxx@mydomaine.com';
$mail->AddAddress('xxx@yahoo.fr');
$mail->AddReplyTo('xxx@mydomaine.com'); 
$mail->Subject='test';
$mail->Body='example for mail';
```

if i make From address yyy@mydomaine.com  it is work but if i change it to example yyy@gmail.com or yahoo.fr it do not work. this the error message 
SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: xxx@yahoo.fr
SMTP server error: 5.7.1 : Relay access denied

Comment: Please refer to http://www.techiepark.com/tutorials/send-emails-using-phpmailer-and-gmail/ for additional info

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use yyy@gmail.com or yyy@yahoo.com as from address, You need to configure respective mail server with authentication(mail account). For example, if you want to configure gmail configure like this..

```
$mailObj->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mailObj->Port = '465';
$mailObj->Username = 'yyyy@gmail.com';
$mailObj->Password = 'passwordofaboveaccount';
```

Now

```
$mailObj->From='xxx@gmail.com';
```

will work

Comment: if i use this code 

    $mail = new PHPmailer();
 $mail->IsSMTP();
 $mail->Host='mail.mydomaine.com';
 $mail->From='xxx@mydomaine.com';
 $mail->AddAddress('yyy@mydomaine.com');
 $mail->AddReplyTo('xxx@mydomaine.com'); 
 $mail->Subject='test';
 $mail->Body='example for mail';


but the first code don't working. 
Of course my code on server.

Comment: No i don't like to use gmail or yahoo but mydomaine.com  and send mail for all : xx@mydomaine.com; xx@gmail.com; .....

Comment: @Hearaman is right. Gmail and Yahoo won't allow you to send as if it was FROM them unless you send through their servers. The best you can do if you want to send through your server is use the Reply-To address. In order to masquerade your From address as if it was from Google your server would have to be in Google's allowed list of senders which isn't going to happen.

Comment: Please configure mail authentication account, means $mail->Username = 'yyyy@mydomain.com'; $mail->Password = 'password';. Here you need to use from address some thing like $mail->From='any@mydomain.com' Otherwise mails will go to spam.

Comment: Now i will to use gmail server i change my php file to this code  $mail = new PHPmailer();
 $mail->IsSMTP();
 $mailObj->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
 $mailObj->Port = '465';
 $mailObj->Username = 'xxx@gmail.com';
 $mailObj->Password = '******';
 $mail->From='xxx@gmail.com';
 $mail->AddAddress('yyyy@yahoo.fr');    i don't have any problem and message for success of send mail is appear  but in  yyyy@yahoo.fr    i don't have any mail (inbox , spam)

Answer (score 1):

you can add the mail for site....

```
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = '465';
$mail->Username = 'yyy@gmail.com';//your mail is valuable
$mail->Password = 'password';//your mail pass
```

if you need to change the mail to yahoo then simply change the host name with the yahoo smtp.......

Answer (score 0):

How could you ever send email with someone elses email address? You can ofcourse only send from your own domain, if this PHP code is on your server.

Comment: if i use this code 

    $mail = new PHPmailer();
 $mail->IsSMTP();
 $mail->Host='mail.mydomaine.com';
 $mail->From='xxx@mydomaine.com';
 $mail->AddAddress('yyy@mydomaine.com');
 $mail->AddReplyTo('xxx@mydomaine.com'); 
 $mail->Subject='test';
 $mail->Body='example for mail';


but the first code don't working. 
Of course my code on server.

Answer (score 0):

do you have the following, yes?

```
$mailObj->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
$mailObj->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
```

Comment: I added it but the some problem :(

Comment: port 465 go with "ssl"; use 25 for no ssl

Comment: use the $mailObj->SetFrom() for setting the from-address which also set some other like ReplyTo

Comment: $mailObj->SetFrom('yyy@gmail.com','TliliDroid');

Comment: perhaps the ->AddReplyTo messes with what you give in ->From; use only ->SetFrom and comment the 2 above